# Undefined priority of repeated keys

Tags: javascript, parsing, security

While working with API I encountered a problem that JavaScript doesn't recognize which key will be first.

Let's say I'm just trying to duplicate a JSON key
For example:
`Test = { "bro":1, "bro":2}`
What will be the total value for bro when generating such a query: 1 or 2, or will there be an error?
I found information that according to the official standard, both are possible. The reason why this is possible, it seems to me, is because the standard is pre-made in such a way as not to break backward compatibility with pre-specification parsers.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.